# In MacHg is there a way to only see changesets that modified a specific file?

Tags: mercurial

Using Tortoise Hg you can right-click on a file and view its revision history, which only shows those changesets in the repository that changed that specific file.

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing in MacHg? If I view the full revision history I see all the changesets and the search tool filters the list down on commit messages and other meta data, but I can't find a method to filter the list to only those changes impacting a given file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the search field in the history view does work, as described in the [Mac Hg FAQ](http://machghelp.jasonfharris.com/kb/exploring-repositories/how-do-i-view-the-update-history-for-a-single-file).